# How do views or parts of the appication communicate with each other in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, publish-subscribe

I am researching on emberjs latly. I have a question on how do views communicate with each other. I know views do not communicate so the question could be either Route or Controller (view model).

Coming from other frameworks and languages I used a pattern which is called pubsub to propagate the information that a certain information has changed and other views (who are interested in this information) would subscribe and could update if the event/message was sent.

Is this also a pattern which applies to the emberjs philosophy? Or how would you update different parts on the UI based on changes in an other part?

A (very) simple example could be:

```
-> Application
  -> Navigation which contains a Link to the posts route with a number of current posts (count)
  -> Posts route would have a list of post with details (and add,delete,etc) actions
```

Now when I create a post it would be added to the list and how should I updated the post count in the navigation?

Obviously this could/should be also applicable for more complex examples.
As a note:
At the moment I have also a server route for the stats. So the navigation and its posts count will be fetched from the server and its not bound to the length of the post array...

What is the best way to handle something like this with emberjs?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in http://emberjs.com/guides/views/ , Views are basically used to handle user events and create reusable components. However some useful facts are,

**1**.The contents that a `View`'s template will present are based on the model and properties that the corresponding `Controller` holds.

**2**.A `View` can access it's corresponding `Controller` as well as any other associated controllers (via the `needs` property http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) and the data that they hold.

**3**.If Views share a model then they will be updated whenever the model changes. For this to occur there are a few cases, one of the most common is inserting views through the `{{view}}` helper.(http://emberjs.com/guides/views/inserting-views-in-templates/)

**4**.If Views or their corresponding controllers are observing or are bound to common properties then they will also be updated (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/).

With these facts in mind this particular problem could be tackled based on the requirements of the specific system. For example some options could be *(accompanied with rough examples)*,

- If all your data/posts are available when executing crud actions then binding to the enumeration of posts (http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/) of the `Posts` Controller could update a computed property of the associated `Navigation` controller that displays the total posts.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/huqoq/1/edit

- If data is lazily loaded, e.g. in pages, then having the `Navigation` controller `observe` the changes on the `Posts` Controller enumeration of posts, could trigger a request to the server to retrieve the total number of posts or update a counter value depending on the action (create/delete).

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jomes/1/edit

- The `Navigation` View could simply be inserted within the `Posts` View and share the same model and have a computed property displaying total posts.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/xujap/1/edit

- The `Navigation` View could be rendered via the `{{render}}` helper with the model of posts.(http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/)

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/gihep/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straightforward in Ember.js. There are different ways of setting this up, but the basics are the following: Since Ember is an MVC framework, all of your views will have access to the same underlying data. As you make changes to the data Ember's data bindings will make sure all views that care about that change will be updates.

So specifically for the example you mentioned you could simply include `{{ content.length }}` in your template, which will display the number of items in your ArrayController (which is auto-generated by Ember, although you could override it if your wanted to add functionality) . Have a look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NQKvy/683/).

Templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>ember-latest jsfiddle</h1>    
    {{ render 'navigation' controllers.users.content }}
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="navigation">
      <h2>Index Content ({{ content.length }}):</h2>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
  {{#each}}
      <li>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</li>
  {{/each}}
   </ul>
   <button {{action 'add'}}>Add</button>    
</script>
```

Routes:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
        this.controllerFor('users').set('content', this.store.findAll('user'));
    }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.findAll('user');
    }
});
```

Controllers:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['users'],
});

App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    actions: {
        add: function() {
            this.get('store').createRecord('user', {firstName: 'New', lastName: 'Person'});
        }
    }
});
```

As you click the button you'll see how the count automatically updates. Note that in this case we only have one route (to illustrate data bindings better), but this would work just as well if you had an index route (to list all posts) and a detail route (to show a single post).

Welcome to the magical world of Ember.js :)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and the code example. The thing is that count would be outside of the IndexController scope. Navigation is in the Application template above the {{outlet}}. And count should be pulled from the server not bound to the length via ajax

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. All of that is possible - I used DS.FixturesAdapter to simulate a server. Normally you would use something like DS.RESTAdapter, which would handle your communication with your backend. So for example when you call `this.store.findAll('user')` it would dispatch a `GET` request to `/users` and your data (as well as your 'count') would update automatically. In my edit I also removed the computed property `count`, since Handlebars lets you get the length of the content via `{{ content.length }}`